# Add more functions to module.exports

Tags: node.js

```
// index.js //
module.exports = (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello World!");
};
```

This function is called when I require the file.

```
let index = require("./index.js");
app.get("/", index);
```

Can I add some another functions to `module.exports`?

Like this:

```
// index.js //
module.exports = (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello World!");
},
hi: (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hi!");
};
```

```
let index = require("./index.js");
app.get("/", index);
app.get("/hi", index.hi);
```

Comment: `module.exports.hi = ...`? But I'd generally stick to exporting a function *or* an object, not a function with a bunch of bonus properties.

Comment: Why would I generally stick to exporting a function or an object?

Comment: I mean one or the other, not a hybrid.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use:

```
function index(req, res) {
  res.send("Hello World!");
}

function hi(req, res) {
  res.send("hi!");
}

module.exports = {
  Index: index,
  Hi: hi
}
```

Then reference as you mentioned:

```
let index = require("./index.js");
app.get("/", index.Index);
app.get("/hi", index.Hi);
```

Comment: I know that way. But I would like to have the function `index` and others. So the function `index` is called in `let index` and I just do `app.get("/", index);`. But when I call some _attribute_ from the `index`, it'll call the another function, like: `app.get("/hi", index.hi)` calls function `hi`. I know, it does not matter how I can do it, but it makes sense for me.